# I want to install lucee on my VPS but cannot as I am getting error during post installation

Tags: lucee

I want to install lucee on my VPS but cannot as I am getting error during post installation.

```
Error running /opt/lucee/sys/install_mod_cfml.sh -m install -f
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf -d /usr/local/apache/modules -c
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -k
a9681d10cecf61fea7aa9e4bd203e096e7e5a0c94fa1534d32cf6c0cd82f7d2c: httpd: Syntax
error on line 570 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
modules/mod_cfml.so into server: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not
found (required by /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_cfml.so)
```

Can anybody point me in a right direction, how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the auto-detection of your Apache version or bit-type is failing. This means you'll need to install mod_cfml manually, or live without it.

When you run the Lucee installer, simply un-check the option to install mod_cfml. From there, you can install mod_cfml manually by following the instructions found on this page:

http://www.modcfml.org/index.cfm/install/web-server-components/

You can also add hosts to your tomcat config manually by editing your Tomcat server.xml file directly, and restarting Tomcat/Lucee every time you add a new host.